# In the IDEA development environment, how does maven manage the downloading of dependencies for java projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm coding in IDEA . When I use maven, I encounter a strange problem.

Firstly, the IDEA configured a local maven enviroment, and use a local configuration file `setting.xml`, it configured a nexus node.

Second, I imported a project from eclipse, based maven.

I'm sure that the `setting.xml`100% correct. But the IDEA not download jar from nexus, but from maven url.

I don't know what happend.

I clean `~\m2` folder, and clean 'lib' floder. but it also not success.

I want to know how to IDEA use maven download jar, and how to decide url，and what circumstances will download failed.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-build-execution-deployment.html

I hidden the groupId,artifactId,name and password but I'm sure it is right.

I hidden some depency, it too many.

The Parent Pom is in nexus.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <localRepository>D:\Software\maven\repo</localRepository>

  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>

  <proxies>
  </proxies>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>name</username>
      <password>pwd</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>y-snapshots</id>
      <username>name</username>
      <password>pwd</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>y-releases</id>
      <username>name</username>
      <password>pwd</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
     <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://192.168.31.169:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>


  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.s</groupId>
        <artifactId>ss</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>s-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Check if your project pom has repositories mentioned in it

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings:File->Settings
[image]

Comment: I'm sure the maven home directory and user setting file is both local,  and the local repository has ooverrided, and the setting.xml has only one mirrors, but the download url is not nexus url,It is worth noting that I need to use vpn proxy to the internal network download jar

Comment: Check if pom.xml specifies a repository address

Comment: I update the question , add pom file and setting.xml

Comment: File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories